# Deinterlacing in iOS ffmpeg framework

Tags: ios, ffmpeg

since av_picture_deinterlace became deprecated, i have a problem figuring out how exactly I can apply filter to an AVFrame, especially deinterlace filter in ios. Sample code would be really helpfull

Comment: A good start may be `doc/examples/filtering_video.c`. FFmpeg has several deinterlacing filters such as yadif.

Comment: I'm trying to init filters, but AVFilter *buffersrc  = avfilter_get_by_name("buffer");
    AVFilter *buffersink = avfilter_get_by_name("buffersink"); both return NULL. Any ideas why this could happen ?
P.S. I'm trying to apply the filter to live stream

Comment: avfilter_register_all();   is required before filters can be accessed using avfilter_get_by_name().  Also make sure that you don't have --disable-filters in your build config for ffmpeg.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ - applying filter in ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31163120/c-applying-filter-in-ffmpeg)

Answer (score 0):

See the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31163120/c-applying-filter-in-ffmpeg) on Stack Overflow.  It has everything apart from avfilter_register_all() to make it work.